# O que há de novo no R 3.3.3?

Tags: r

O R-core team lançou em 06/03/2017 a [versão 3.3.3 do `R`](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/NEWS.html). Desde então, alguns pacotes estão lançando mensagens como esta:

> package �nome_do_pacote� was built under R version 3.3.3

1. O que há de novo no `R 3.3.3`?
2. Vale a pena instalar o nova versão?
3. Terei de reinstalar todos pacotes que uso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [Aqui tem a lista do que há de novo no `R 3.3.3`](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/NEWS.R-3.3.3.html). Como são 3.137 caracteres de informação, acho contraproducente copiar e colar tudo por aqui. Dê uma olhada no link para ver o que mudou.
2. Defina "vale a pena". Dependendo do teu uso do programa, até mesmo uma versão 1.x pode ser útil. Particularmente, eu gosto de manter atualizados todos os programas do meu computador. Isto inclui o `R` e seus pacotes. O mensagem `package "nome_do_pacote" was built under R version 3.3.3` só está te avisando que `"nome_do_pacote"` foi feito e testado com a versão `3.3.3` do `R`. Pode ser que haja algum problema se `"nome_do_pacote"` for utilizado numa versão anterior do programa. Mas pode ser que não haja problema algum. É só um aviso mesmo.
3. Veja a resposta 2. Não é *preciso* reinstalar todos os pacotes, mas é *sugerido* que se faça. Pacotes atualizados podem ter bugs corrigidos, por exemplo.